# Flot left and position absolute

Tags: position, css-float, absolute

When hover on black boxes, red one appears, but is covered by another element. How to fix this?

```
<div class="gridek grid"><div class="tooltip">hej</div></div>
<div class="gridek grid"><div class="tooltip">hej</div></div>
<div class="gridek grid"><div class="tooltip">hej</div></div>

.grid {width:60px;height:60px;float:left;z-index:5;position:relative;background:black}
.grid:hover .tooltip {display:block}
.tooltip {display:none;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background:red;padding:50px;z-index:7}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k7bsutac/)

Comment: Please post code that demonstrates the problem in the question. People can't read or search links to external sites, and links can expire.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k7bsutac/

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29134491/edit) your question to include the code *in the question*. Stack Overflow is designed so people can search for answers on the site, and that doesn't work if you only post links to the code. And if the link is changed or expires the question will not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the red boxes are cropped due to z-index. You can change the z-index of a hovered parrent by simple `.grid:hover { z-index:6 }`

https://jsfiddle.net/k7bsutac/1/

```
<div class="gridek grid"><div class="tooltip">hej</div></div>
<div class="gridek grid"><div class="tooltip">hej</div></div>
<div class="gridek grid"><div class="tooltip">hej</div></div>
.grid {width:60px;height:60px;float:left;z-index:5;position:relative;background:black}
.grid:hover .tooltip {display:block}
.grid:hover { z-index:6 }
.tooltip {display:none;position:abolute;top:30px;right:30px;background:red;padding:50px;z-index:7}
```

and the result will be:
[image]

If you need something else, please comment :)